# Creating a ‘bounding polygon’ for a set of points (preferably with GGplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, Lets say that I have a set of x and y points, how can I get a `geom_polygon` to encapsulate all points, ie, what is the best way to create a 'bounding' polygon for the set?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
mydata <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(mydata,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_polygon()
```

The above code is pretty clear that the result is unsatisfactory (result below).
[image: Result]